# How to combine inequalities

Tags: inequality

If $u,v$ are real numbers and $|u-3|<1/3$ and $|v-3|<2/3$ then show that $|v-u|<1$.

I'm unsure about how to combine this inequalities and simplify.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with the triangle inequality?

Comment: Draw a picture.

Answer (score 1):

By the Triangle Inequality, we have:
$$
|u-v|=|(u-3)-(v-3)|\leq |u-3|+|v-3|<\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{3}=1.
$$

Comment: thank you, I just didn't notice the second step.

Comment: You welcome. :-)